# Spring Batch - How to output Thread and Grid number to console or log

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my Spring Batch configuration I have this:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("myJob");
    asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(15);
    asyncTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("SrcToDest");
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

And also I have a "master-step" where I am setting the grid-size as per below:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("masterStep")
public Step masterStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner("step1", partitioner()).step(step1())
            .taskExecutor(threadpooltaskExecutor()).taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .gridSize(10).build();
}
```

In my case, I see only "Thread-x" at the end when "myjob" finishes with "COMPLETED" status.

Questions

1. In order to monitor how can I print the thread number to the console/log throughout the execution process? i.e. "myjob" start to finish
2. Is there some way I can get the output to console/log to see the grid action too?

I could not find any example or anywhere in Spring Guides for these.

Comment: For thread number, I was able to fix. I had to add the following to my "step1" - .taskExecutor(threadpooltaskExecutor()).taskExecutor(taskExecutor()) and I am able to see the thread numbers on console nicely. Still looking how to display grid numbers to console.

Answer (score 0):

> Still looking how to display grid numbers to console

This depends on your partitioner. You can add a log statement in your partitioner and show the grid size. So at partitioning time, it's on your side.

At partition handling time, Spring Batch will show a log statement at debug level of each execution of the worker step.

Comment: MyBean - @Bean("partitioner")
 @StepScope
 public Partitioner partitioner() {
  log.info("In Partitioner");
  MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
  ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
  Resource[] resources = null;
  try {
   resources = resolver.getResources("*.csv");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  partitioner.setResources(resources);
  partitioner.partition(mycustombatchpartitionsize);
  return partitioner;
 } Where and what I can to get grid numbers on console/log file?

Comment: In case, you need, here is my full config - https://github.com/ajkr195/springbatchmultithread2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/batch/config/BatchConfiguration.java. Please suggest.